# Not able to send mail through yahoo server using grails mail plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) and am setting up an smtp request as follows

```
grails {
   mail {
      host = "smtp.correo.yahoo.es"
      port = 465
      username = "myuser"
      password = "mypassword"
      props = [ "mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                       "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                       "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                       "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"  ]
   }
}
```

Even though I have provided correct username/password, I am not able to send any mail.

Comment: Can you post the error please?

Answer (score 0):

I try to send emails through Gmail and, after a few emails (maybe twenty or thirty), the server begun to block it. Maybe Yahoo have too a similar block system. Now my systems are sending emails through Amazon SMS, if you are curious about that I can show you how configure it.

Check Yahoo policies about sending emails.